# I keep on getting Uncaught ReferenceError: success is not defined in browser console

Tags: jquery

I have this AJAx query

```
   var ajaxQuery =  $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
url: url+'/OMS/oms1/orderinsertservice?ordersplitjson='+ordersplitjson+'&customer_id='+cust_id+'&homedelivery='+homedelivery+'&seatnum='+seatnum+'&locationname='+location_nam+'&rownum='+rownum,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
    beforeSend: function()
            { 
              $("#loader").show(); 
            }, 
            success: function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        });
```

Why am i getting Uncaught ReferenceError: success is not defined in browser console  , could anybody please help me ??

Comment: Are you by any chance doing this `ajaxQuery.success()` anywhere?

Comment: I am using ajaxQuery.done(